# How can you read data from columns in a text file into 3 1D numpy arrays in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have data in a text file with 3 columns and 4 rows like this:

```
 5 6.4 17
 6 5.8 16
 7 5.5 3.9
 8 5.3 10.4
```

I want to read this data from the text file into 3 1D arrays each with 4 elements

I have this code:

`import numpy as np
with open('data.txt','rt') as filedata:
        values=np.genfromtxt('data.txt', unpack=True)`

this has created a 2D (3,4) array. 
I managed to split it into 3 subarrays using `np.slice(values,4)` but then I didn't know how to rename and subsequently use those subarrays

Comment: You can simply do `a,b,c = np.genfromtxt('data.txt', unpack=True)` and this should create 3 1D numpy arrays with names `a`, `b` and `c`.

Comment: @Ardweaden Thank you that really helps!

Comment: @Ardweaden - Can you change the data type of the respective 1D numpy arrays within the numpy routine you use?

Answer (score 1):

You can use python's slice notation:

```
import numpy as np
with open('data.txt','rt') as filedata:
        values = np.genfromtxt('data.txt', unpack=True)

array1 = values[:, 0]
array2 = values[:, 1]
array3 = values[:, 2]
```

When you use slicing the first value defines the range in rows and the second in columns. So by typing `values[:, 0]` you say give me all elements in 0th column. The semicolon lets you specify a range. For example, `values[0:2, 0]` says give me the first two elements in the 0th column. You can look at the slicing notation in more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation).